# How is Pre Master Secret related to Client.random or Server.random if DH KEX is RSA

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, random-number-generator, tls

For TLS 1.2 cipher Suite **AES256-GCM-SHA384**, **RSA** is KEX(key exchagne algorithm). As per standards of RSA Diffie Hellman KEX, after 'ServerHello' message client gets server certificate and it generates a 48 byte random number which is '**pre master secret**' and sends it to server. This ensures both have setup pre master secret.

Are **client.random** and **server.random** anyway related(mathemetically) to pre master secret?

As per my understanding (after researching on web), **server.random** prevents handshake replay attack in ECDH. How is RSAKEX preventing handshake replay attack?

Are they only significant after master secret generation and succeeding steps, but not in preventing handshake replay attack?

Comment: The pre-master secret and the random fields are unrelated but both are used to compute the master secret (it should be the same for ECDH).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Since that's the case replay attack is mitigated by encrypting pre master secret with server certificate. By sending encrypted packet attacker could never establish connection(client like) with server as it can't derive master secret and subsequent keys.

Comment: That ciphersuite (using the nonstandard OpenSSL name) uses `RSA` keyexchange, period. There is no 'RSA Diffie Hellman' kexexchange. In _earlier_ protocols there were `DH_RSA` and `DH_DSS` -- static Diffie-Hellman with RSA or DSA _CA_ -- but in TLS1.2 those are combined, see the paragraph after the table on page 49 of RFC5246, and similarly for `ECDH_{RSA,ECDSA}`, see A.7 on page 78.  In general for all questions about details of **TLS1.2 protocol see RFC5246** (and for extensions other than sigalgs the relevant other RFC).